# CakePHP 1.3: How Do I Use Find to Only Retrieve Articles that are within 12 Months From Today

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to retrieve articles that are within 1 year from the today's date. Basically, I would like to split the article section of my site into new articles (within 1 year) and archived articles (older than 1 year). How do I change the following statement to make sure this happens?

```
$articles = $this->Article->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Article.title',
            'Article.body',
            'Article.slug',
            'Article.id',
            'Article.image',
            'Article.created'
        ),
        'order' => 'Article.created DESC',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Article.created >' => //What do I need to add here
        )
    )
);
```

I will do the same thing for archived articles but with different condition:

```
$archived_articles = $this->Article->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'fields' => array(
            'Article.title',
            'Article.body',
            'Article.slug',
            'Article.id',
            'Article.image',
            'Article.created'
        ),
        'order' => 'Article.created DESC',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Article.created <' => //What do I need to add here
        )
    )
);
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
'Article.created <' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 year"));
```

Comment: AWESOME! It works great! I just had to change the `<` to `>` as such `'Article.created >' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-1 year"))` for `$articles` and keep `<` for `$archived_articles`. Thank you very much!